# openxlsx: How to copy a workbook worksheet (or its formatted data) into a different worksheet?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I want to load a workbook/sheet from an excel file that has complex formatting that can't be applied using `openxlsx` (ie cells where some of the text is italic and some is not) and then append the formatted data from that worksheet at the bottom of an existing worksheet.

I'm aware that `cloneWorksheet()` will copy the ENTIRE sheet, but i specifically want to add data from one worksheet into another existing worksheet.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "sheet")

writeData(wb, sheet, mydata) #assume mydata is a data frame

wb2 <- loadWorkbook("myfile.xlsx")

writeData(wb = wb, sheet = sheet, x = wb2, startRow = ncol(mydata) + 1) #I know this doesn't work
```

For that last line, I want to take the formatted data from the worksheet in wb2 and add it after the existing data in the sheet of wb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the issue with loadWorkbook() is that it doesn't allow you to "write" the data using writeDate function but retains the styles. And reverse, readWorkbook() permits you to write the data to any other sheet, but does not preserve the style. So you need to combine the styles (and applicable rows/cols) from a loadWorkbook with the writeable data from readWorkbook. Let's say I have the below wb with various styles:

```
library(openxlsx)

#Create original file with various formats

wb <- createWorkbook()

big_font <- createStyle(fontSize = 20)
red_font <- createStyle(fontColour = "red")
border_cell <- createStyle(borderStyle = "thick", borderColour ="purple", border = "TopBottomLeftRight")
bold_blue_big <- createStyle(fontColour = "blue", fontSize = 25, textDecoration = "bold")

addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "format")

writeData(wb, sheet = "format", mtcars)

addStyle(wb, sheet = "format", rows = 1:5, cols = 1:3, style = big_font, gridExpand = TRUE)

addStyle(wb, sheet = "format", rows = 6:7, cols = 1:3, style = red_font, gridExpand = TRUE)

addStyle(wb, sheet = "format", rows = 8:15, cols = 1:3, style = border_cell, gridExpand = TRUE)

addStyle(wb, sheet = "format", rows = 14:20, cols = 1:3, style = bold_blue_big, gridExpand = TRUE, stack = TRUE)

openXL(wb)

saveWorkbook(wb, "path/format.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

getStyles(wb)[[2]]

> getStyles(wb)[[2]]
A custom cell style. 

 Cell formatting: GENERAL 
 Font colour: #FF0000
```

The wb has set styles and the second style is color #FF0000 or red

If loadWorkbook reads in the xlsx file of wb just written, it will retain the styles

```
#Preserves styles
format_wb <- loadWorkbook("path/format.xlsx")
getStyles(format_wb)[[2]] #returns styles

> getStyles(format_wb)[[2]]
A custom cell style. 

 Cell formatting: GENERAL 
 Font name: Calibri 
 Font size: 11 
 Font colour: #FF0000
```

But not when readWorkwook is used. We will still want this writeable data to add to the new, merged

```
#Loses styles but writable data

write_wb <- readWorkbook("path/format.xlsx")
getStyles(write_wb) #returns no styles
```

Basically needed a specialized function to combine information from both of these. It would need to be modified if only a select few styles wanted to be copied over or specific style, but otherwise - if full duplication of all formatting:

This function has several inputs but it basically has:

1. the formatted workbook where the styles are coming from,
2. the workbook that the styles are being applied to,
3. the sheetname of the workbook,
4. and 5. and whether rows/columns should be added. This is for when you want to preserve the exact formatting from wb1 for cells A1:J25 but you are for example, adding wb1 contents to wb2, and wanting to format wb1.data at A150:J175. These defaults are otherwise set to 0 if no rows/cols adjustments should be made

The format_wb$styleObjects prints the style and also the rows and columns where that style is found. From there, it is just extracting the distinct values for each row (these_rows) and col (these_cols) as you sequence along all the styles in the format_wb. Add the style by referencing it with getStyles and apply to these_rows and these_cols. If not starting from the first row and first column (i.e., rows and columns are added), then the arguments addrow and addcol will need to change from default 0

#Function ----

```
apply_old_format <- 
    
    function(format_wb, new_wb, sheetname, addrow = 0, addcol = 0){
        
        for(i in seq_along(format_wb$styleObjects)){
            
            these_rows <- unique(format_wb$styleObjects[[i]]$rows)
            these_cols <- unique(format_wb$styleObjects[[i]]$cols)
            
            addStyle(new_wb, sheet = sheetname, 
                     style = getStyles(format_wb)[[i]], 
                     rows = addrow + (these_rows), 
                     cols = addcol + (these_cols), 
                     gridExpand = TRUE, stack = TRUE)
            
        }
    }
```

Now we can create a new workbook that will combine an existing data set, in this case iris, and appending the mtcars  data set that was formatted in the **original wb** and loaded in as **format_wb** for its styles, and read in to be writeable as **write_wb.**

Example has long data on first sheet and wide data on second sheet depending on where second data set is appended

```
#Create merged product

new_wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(new_wb, sheetName = "iris_cars_long")
addWorksheet(new_wb, sheetName = "iris_cars_wide")

writeData(new_wb, sheet = "iris_cars_long", iris, colNames = TRUE)
writeData(new_wb, sheet = "iris_cars_long", write_wb, startRow = 152, startCol = 1)

apply_old_format(format_wb = format_wb, new_wb = new_wb, sheetname = "iris_cars_long") #adds to top part of iris data
apply_old_format(format_wb = format_wb, new_wb = new_wb, sheetname = "iris_cars_long", addrow = dim(iris)[1] +1) #adds to cars using dimension of data if it is not known, just used as demo can otherwise enter number


writeData(new_wb, sheet = "iris_cars_wide", iris, colNames = TRUE)
writeData(new_wb, sheet = "iris_cars_wide", write_wb, startRow = 1, startCol = length(iris) + 2) #for if you don't know exact length just for demo

apply_old_format(format_wb = format_wb, new_wb = new_wb, sheetname = "iris_cars_wide", addcol = length(iris) +1)

openXL(new_wb)
```